# Does nproc in limits.conf refers to number of processes or number of threads?

Tags: linux, ulimit, thread

If I want to check if I got to the max of the nproc value should I do:

```
ps -ef | wc -l
```

Or

```
ps -efL | wc -l
```

Does nproc in `limits.conf` refers to number of processes or number of threads?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On Linux it refers to the number of threads. From [`setrlimit(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getrlimit.2.html) (which is the system call used to set the limits):

> **RLIMIT_NPROC**
>
> The maximum number of processes (or, more precisely on Linux, threads) that can be created for the real user  ID
>                 of  the  calling process.  Upon encountering this limit, `fork(2`) fails with the error `EAGAIN`.  This limit is not
>                 enforced for processes that have either the `CAP_SYS_ADMIN` or the `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE` capability.

So `ps -efL | wc -l` would be more appropriate, *however* the limits in `limits.conf` apply per login session (see [`limits.conf(5)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/limits.conf.5.html) for details).

Comment: So the nproc limit does not limit the root?

Comment: No, it doesn't limit `root`.

Comment: another question - how come there are lines in limit.conf of limits for root if it does not limit root?

Comment: Other limits do apply to `root`, for example `core`. It's `nproc` which doesn't apply to `root`, not all the limits.